# abnormal 'flat, BNL join' on mariadb 5.5

Tags: mariadb

I have two mariadb 5.5 instances and each instance has the exactly same data and my.cnf parameters. (Actually, I have copied all files from old server to the new one.)

When I run a query, the one is fast( < 1sec) and shows me query explain like below... (host#1)

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                                                                                                                                  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | TABLE1          | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 130     | NULL                                                                                                                                                 |   9792 | Using where; Using index                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ref   | key0          | key0    | 135     | testdb.TABLE1.COL1,testdb.TABLE1.COL2,testdb.TABLE1.COL3,testdb.TABLE1.COL4,testdb.TABLE1.COL5                                                       |     30 |                                              |
|    2 | DERIVED     | TABLE2          | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                                                                                                                                                 | 299012 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The another does long running ( more than 15 seconds) and shows me different explain like below...(host#2)

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys | key               | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | TABLE1          | index | NULL          | PRIMARY           | 130     | NULL |   8123 | Using index                                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ALL   | NULL          | NULL              | NULL    | NULL | 294954 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    2 | DERIVED     | TABLE2          | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY           | 8       | NULL | 294954 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

When I accidently set `derived_with_keys` to `off` on host#1, result is same with host#2 and I think host#1 choose `derived_with_keys` operation which host#2 does not.

How can I enforce my new server to use `derived_with_keys`?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the query.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: What specific version?  See https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-4610 .  Any chance you could upgrade; 5.5 is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Two different character set were there.(UTF8 and LATIN1)

After `ALTER TABLE TABLE2 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8` it works properly.

Thanks Rick James.